# Adding Dates and Checking NULL values in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I've been trying to figure out a query which will do the followings:

1. Check `last_service` record and add `delivery_frequency` record which is day-based to `next_service` date field in mysql.
2. However, if `last_service` is `NULL` or `Empty` then update `last_service` to today's date and do the step 1 afterwards.

I know how to do the step one which is the following query:

```
UPDATE events SET next_service = DATE_ADD(last_service,INTERVAL 14 DAY) WHERE order_product_id = 3;
```

But somewhat I found Step 2nd trickier. Could some one show me how to do that?

I am consuming these with PHP but I don't want to handle this part with PHP doing double query or something.

You can think what I am looking for as following:

```
UPDATE events SET next_service = IF last_service IS NOT NULL OR '' THEN
DATE_ADD(last_service,INTERVAL 14 DAY) ELSE SET last_service = CURRENT_DATE AND
DATE_ADD(last_service,INTERVAL 14 DAY) END IF WHERE order_product_id = 3;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE events
SET
   last_service = coalesce(last_service, CURRENT_DATE),
   next_service = DATE_ADD(coalesce(last_service, CURRENT_DATE), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
WHERE order_product_id = 3;
```

Coalesce returns the first non-null value, so that

```
coalesce('2011-12-31', CURRENT_DATE)
```

returns `2011-12-31`

and

```
coalesce(null, CURRENT_DATE)
```

returns `2012-02-06` which is `CURRENT_DATE`

Comment: OK, seriously this is awesome how you came up with this answer. Looks like exactly what I've been looking for.